# Function always return null when call it

Tags: php

I'm relatively new in the field so please bear with me. I have a class with few function inside. It uses workerman to start an server. I'm trying to load some data on server boot (`function load()`) and then using that data to display on the page when ask for some `$key`. Something like API calls.

Data in the csv is

```
doctor,31234-32223
police officer,342-341
firefighter,543-3345
worker,12223
developer,120045
```

```
class App 
{

    public $getPair = null;
    public $dataToLoad= []; 
    protected $dispatcher = null;

   /**
     * start
     */
    public function start()
    {
        $this->dispatcher = \FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(\FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
            foreach ($this->routeInfo as $method => $callbacks) {
                foreach ($callbacks as $info) {
                    $r->addRoute($method, $info[0], $info[1]);
                }
            }
        });

        \Workerman\Worker::runAll();
    }

    function load()
    {
        $files = "load.csv";
                    
        foreach($files as $file) {
            if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $dataToLoad[$data[1]] = $data[0]; 
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }

        return $this->dataToLoad;
    }

    function getData($getPair) {
        foreach ($this->dataToLoad as $key => $value){
            if($getPair === $key){
                return array($key.','.$value);
            } else {
                echo "missing";
            }
        } 
    }

    /**
     * @param TcpConnection $connection
     * @param Request $request
     * @return null
     */
    public function onMessage($connection, $request)
    {
        static $callbacks = [];
        try {
            $path = $request->path();
            $method = $request->method();
            $key = $method . $path;
            $callback = $callbacks[$key] ?? null;
            if ($callback) {
                $connection->send($callback($request));
                return null;
            }

            $ret = $this->dispatcher->dispatch($method, $path);
            if ($ret[0] === Dispatcher::FOUND) {
                $callback = $ret[1];
                if (!empty($ret[2])) {
                    $args = array_values($ret[2]);
                    $callback = function ($request) use ($args, $callback) {
                        return $callback($request, ... $args);
                    };
                }
                $callbacks[$key] = $callback;
                $connection->send($callback($request));
                return true;
            } else {
                $connection->send(new Response(404, [], '<h1>404 Not Found</h1>'));
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $connection->send(new Response(500, [], (string)$e));
        }
    }
```

Then I have `index.php` with following

```
use Mark\App;

$api = new App('http://0.0.0.0:3000');
$api->count = 4; // process count
$api->load(); //load data

$api->get('/key/{key}', function ($request, $key) {
    return $api->getData("doctor");
});

$api->start();
```

The error is in the `index.php` file on the line `return $api->getData("key");`

> Error: Call to a member function getData() on null

> PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $api

Why `getData()` is null in this case and why is undefined since I have initialized it when I assign it on `new App()...` above?

ps. The server is started correctly and without errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anonymous/closure function does not have scope to `$api`, so this can be passed with `use`.

```
$api->get('/key/{key}', function ($request, $key) use ($api) {
    return $api->getData("doctor");
});
```

Side note: the `getData` function is missing `public`.

Comment: +1. In addition to this, the `load()` function never assigns anything to `$this->dataToLoad`. Before leaving the function, assign the value of `$dataToLoad` to `$this->dataToLoad`.

Comment: @drew010, doesn't `return $this->dataToLoad;` in `load()` do this? returning the dataLoad?

Comment: What drew mentions, is note that you build the `$dataToLoad` variable within the loop, but then nothing is done with it afterwards. So, _just before_ the `return` in `load`, add a `$this->dataToLoad = $dataToLoad;`.

Comment: @Rob, That returns the variable you want, but nothing was ever actually assigned to it. In the loop, data is assigned to `$dataToLoad`, which is *not* the same as `$this->dataToLoad`. The `$dataToLoad` variable is a separate, local variable in that function that gets automatically created the first time something is assigned to it.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it now. I though exactly that `$dataLoad` is equal to `$this->dataLoad` below. Thank you very much!

Comment: Alternatively, instead of having another variable, use the class reference at the loop instead: `$dataToLoad[$data[1]] = $data[0];` => `$this->dataToLoad[$data[1]] = $data[0];` ... and then the assignment mentioned in my previous comment would not be needed.

Comment: Yes, works that's way too. Thanks